# como puedo quitar estos WARNING

Tags: php

Resulta que siempre que hago algun comando php artisan ... me sale los siguientes errores:

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_tokenizer' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_tokenizer (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_tokenizer.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0**

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_tokenizer' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_tokenizer (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_tokenizer.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in
Unknown on line 0**

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ctype' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ctype (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ctype.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0**

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ctype' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ctype (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_ctype.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_json' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_json (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_json.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0**

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_json' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_json (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_json.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0**

En xampp  config PHP(php.ini) ya des comente las 3 extensiones.

Agradezco me puedan ayudar pues no he podido solucionarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Y ya reiniciaste el apache?, Después de cualquier modificación es necesario reiniciar

Comment: Hola, puede que esto te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027013/how-to-fix-php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-ext-php-cu

Answer (score -1):

Entras a php.ini y buscas error_reporting y sustituyes lo que viene después de =
Quedaría algo asi:

> error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING